# Ideal height of tree structure

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-tree

How can I calculate the ideal height of a tree structure?

When I have this tree
[image: Tree]

I know the height is `4`.

There's a formula that says that the ideal height of a tree is `2 ^ height - 1` but that doesn't make sense to me (since it would be `15`).

Can someone please explain?

Comment: [Perfect Binary Trees](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~cmoreno/ece250/4.05.PerfectBinaryTrees.pdf) - The formula is for the number of nodes, not the height...

Answer (score 2):

Well, first of all, that formula applies only to binary trees.  Second, the ideal **number of nodes** in the tree will be `2^height-1`.  For a saturated binary tree of height `4`, the number of nodes will be `15`.

Comment: If I hadn't the graph in my question but only a word like "wonder" (for a binary tree), can I somehow calculate the height of it, too?

Comment: Do you mean that each letter of the word is one node of the tree?  In that case, you can calculate a range of heights, but not the exact height.  The maximum height will be `6`, for a degenerate tree, and `3` for an ideal tree, because the closest power of `2` that is `> 6` is `8`, which is `2^3`.

Answer (score 0):

That formula is for the maximum number of nodes that can be included in a binary tree of that height. Assuming you want the tree to be as shallow as possible, you want to know the minimum height of such a tree given the number of nodes. So you simply invert:

```
nodes = 2^height - 1
```

to get

```
height = log2(nodes + 1)
```

rounded up.

Answer (score -1):

Height of the tree is the maximum height among all the nodes in the tree. Now say you have a tree

```
                                         1
                                       /   \
                                       2    3
                                      /  \  / \
                                      4  5  6  7
```

the height of the tree is 3(since all path lengths are same so lets say 1-2-5 is maximum) now as there are three levels so no of node at each level

```
                                          1         =2^0
                                       /   \   
                                       2    3      =2^1
                                      /  \  / \
                                      4  5  6  7    =2^2
```

total =2^0 +2^1+2^2= clearly its a gp with sum 2^3-1 ,hence the number of nodes =2^height-1
if you talk about levels(as they start from 0) no of nodes= 2^(level+1)-1